# Implementing C# Class in COM - Handling Custom Properties

Tags: c#, com

I am converting some VB6 code to C#, and it needs to be COM visible. I have a collection class that implements IEnumerator and IEnumerable and this successfully works from the COM client if I create an instance of that class.

```
Set test = CreateObject("Application.Children")
test.Load(parentID)
Print test.Count
```

Now, this class is also exposed as a property of another class

```
interface IParent
{
    string Name {get;}
    Children AllKids {get;}
}
class Parent : IParent
{
    private Children _children;
    private string _parentName;
    public Children AllKids {get => _children}
    public string Name {get => _parentName};
}
```

However, when I try to test this from the COM client

```
set test = CreateObject("Application.Parent")
test.Load(parentID)
Print test.AllKids.Count
```

I get the error

> "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'test.AllKids.Count'"

The Children interface is correctly exposed for COM with its own interface (`IChildren`), as is the `Parent` class.

So in short if the COM creates an instance of the Children class, I have access to the properties and functions of that class, but if I try to access that class from an instance of `Parent`, I cannot.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT :-
I've added the Children class below, although not all the methods required by the interface are written yet.

```
public class Children: IMyCollection<IChild>
    {
        private List<IChild> _baseCollection = new List<IChild>();
        protected int _position = 0;

        public int Count => _baseCollection.Count;

        public IChild Current => _baseCollection[_position];

        public void Add(IChild newItem)
        {
            _baseCollection.Add(newItem);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _baseCollection.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(IChild item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void CopyTo(IChild[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new Enumerator<IChild>(_baseCollection);
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            _position++;
            return (_position < _baseCollection.Count);
        }

        public bool Remove(IChild item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _position = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide Code related to your error message, namely the implementation of the Children class.

Comment: @Cid  I've added the Children class to the post

Comment: It is not very obvious what causes this problem.  Scripting clients can only use the default interface of a C# class and that interface cannot be generic.  Best way to do this is to declare the interface explicitly, like you did with Parent, it must be listed first in the inheritance list.  You can have another look-see at what scripting clients can see by generating the type library with Tlbexp.exe or Regasm.exe /tlb and looking at it with Oleview.exe, File > View Typelib.  It is the [default] one in the coclass declaration that is usable.

Comment: And have AllKids return that interface.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've (more or less) sorted the issue.

My `IMyCollection<IChild>` interface inherited other interfaces, and it appears that that inheritance was causing the problems. Once I reworked that interface the issue appears to be resolved and things are working as intended.